# How can I enforce Lightning UI for all the Users

Tags: lightning

How can I enforce Lightning UI for all the Users. They shouldn't be able to switch to classic.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as of now. That said, someone from Salesforce product team has mentioned that such a functionality would be available via a future release.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DvbpAAC

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to read following articles from Salesforce before enable Lightning.

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_administration

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Experience_FAQ